# Atribuição de valor variável Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho o código JS abaixo e o retorno do JSON não atribui o valor a variável `texto`. Fiz um teste com `alert(data.frase)` e a mensagem veio normalmente.

Alguem saberia dizer o porque a var `texto` não recebe o valor de `data.frase`?

```
var texto=null;
var cod = { cod: codFrase };
$.ajax({
    url: "/Motivos/Getfrase",
    type: 'Post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(cod),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            texto = data.frase;
        }
    }
});
```

Obrigado

Comment: Você verificou o valor de `data.success`, se é `true`?

Comment: onde voce está verificando se o conteudo de texto mudou ou nao?

Comment: Tem certeza que o resultado que vem do servidor é exatamente uma frase com o nome frase? Debugou pra garantir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você provavelmente tem um problema de assíncronia.

Tudo que ocorre dento do `$.ajax` sai da fila padrão de execução do seu javascript e roda assíncronamente.

Ou seja, quando você tenta acessar a variável `texto` o seu código Ajax ainda não foi executado. Já que ele é executado em paralelo.

Você só vai conseguir usar a variável texto dentro do `success` do Ajax, que é quando o Ajax é finalizado.

Caso não queria ficar com o código preso ali, você pode criar uma função que recebe a variável texto e executá-la dentro do `success` passando o valor como parâmetro.

```
var usaTexto = function(texto) {
  // ... aqui você pode fazer o que quiser com a variável texto
}
var cod = { cod: codFrase };
$.ajax({
    url: "/Motivos/Getfrase",
    type: 'Post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(cod),
    success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        usaTexto(data.frase);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Não recomendo a utilização deste método e não sei se funcionará em seu projeto C# MVC. Já tive essa necessidade e resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
var cod = { cod: codFrase };
$.ajax({
   url: "/Motivos/Getfrase",
   type: 'Post',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify(cod),
   async: 0,
   success: function (data) {
       if (data.success) {
           retorno = "<script> texto = '"+data.frase+"'; </script>";
           $("#retorno").html(retorno);
       }
   }
});
```

A opção "async" irá segurar a execução do seu código, retorne a variável no DOM.